# Which word should be plural?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Roses are seen as the most dangerous kind of flower.

In my example, the idea may be *incorrect*, but it's the only simple example I can think of.

Which one of these two words should be plural? ***kind*** or ***flower***?

- Also, should anything be replaced (with an *alternative* sentence *construction*, for example)?
- roses in this case here have a general meaning because there are different varieties of roses.

Comment: What are you trying to give a simple example of?  Why do you think that "kind" or "flower" should be pluralized?

Comment: @Adam, I think one of those words should describe the "roses" as plural( but the "roses" also mentioned as any roses, general roses we can think of),that's why asked. I'm writing something right now in English and should be submitted about the day after tomorrow, so I need a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comparing roses (collectively, as a single class of flower) with all other classes of flower, I suggest using all singulars:

> **The rose is seen as the most dangerous kind of flower.**

As a secondary option, if you are comparing roses (as individual flowers or plants, or as multiple separate species) with other individual flowers, or species of flowers, I suggest using all plurals:

> Roses are seen as the most dangerous kinds of flowers.

Comment: Thank you. As I already expected before, the words can either be plural as well as singular.